# Database query related issue

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table which is as below

```
id  contest_id rank score   team_id
449 59          3   80      26
478 60         13   44      26
647 63          1   99      26
574 79         29   18      29
579 79          7   57      38
608 62         33   18      43
530 73          3   85      53
482 60          8   51      56
654 63          4   79      56
456 59          6   67      56
541 73          6   72      56
```

Now I want to select sum of top 5 score of every team  group by team_id order by sum(score)

Now I am using this query its not working in all ways

```
SELECT team_id as team, sum( score ) as score
FROM contest_result_pk
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT( * )
  FROM contest_result_ck AS c
  WHERE c.team_id = contest_result_pk.team_id
  AND contest_result_pk.score <= c.score
) <= 5
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY sum( score) DESC
```

Comment: select sum(score) from contest_result_pk group by team_id order by sum(score) desc limit 5; ?

Answer (score 2):

That's way too complicated for something so simple...

```
SELECT team_id, SUM(score) AS score
FROM contest_result_pk
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This query will miss the teams that has a tie in score if there are 2 teams with same highest score its score will not be summed so in other words query will result as sum of top 4 scores

Comment: no i want sum of top 5 score of evry team team arranged in desc order

Comment: ah. then you can't do that in mysql. that's a `top n per group`, and it gets VERY ugly in mysql.